# The Timer won’t stop

Tags: javascript, timer, appcelerator, setinterval, clearinterval

I’m working in Appcelerator with Alloy. My app has several screens and I need a timer in one screen. The problem is when I go back to the previous screen, the timer is still running. I need stop it.

I wrote this code:

`Principal.xml`

```
<Alloy>
  <Window id="principal" class="container" backgroundColor="#c0bcc1" onFocus="EnciendoTimers" onBlur="ApagoTimers" onOpen="PosicionaBotones">
....
```

`Principal.js`

```
var timerP;

function EnciendoTimers(){
timerP = setInterval(function(){
    Ti.API.info( "PANTALLA PRINCIPAL.JS. ENTRO EN TIMERP");
    var EstadoLeidoFranja=EstoyEnFranja();
    //Ti.API.info( "Estoy en index.js "+ EstadoLeidoFranja);
    EnciendoReloj=0;
    if (Estado==4){
            EnciendoReloj=1;
    }
    ActualizaPantalla();    
    Ti.API.info( "PANTALLA PRINCIPAL.JS. SALGO DE TIMERP");
    }, 5000);
}

function ApagoTimers(){ //si pierdo foco apago los timers
    Ti.API.info( "PANTALLA PRINCIPAL.JS. APAGO EL  TIMERP");
    clearInterval(timerP);
}
```

When principal is on focus, then `timerP` starts, but when it loses focus, the function `ApagoTimers` runs but won't stop `timerP`. Where is the problem?

Comment: Just curious, is it possible the window is getting created/destroyed more than once and you then have multiple intervals running? If this happens to be the case you could make timerP global to the entire application to get around that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **focus** and **blur** events, I would love to use open and close events like this:

```
<Alloy>
  <Window id="principal" class="container" backgroundColor="#c0bcc1" onOpen="EnciendoTimers" onClose="ApagoTimers">
.......
```

Since, you are calling another function **PosicionaBotones** on ***open*** event, then you can manage these two functions call according to your requirements.